# A question about "insert" function in vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, insert, const-iterator

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert

Cppreference shows: iterator insert( const_iterator pos, const T& value ); and four other overloads.

But why the parameter is const_iterator but not iterator?

Comment: Probably because it does not change the data of the iterator it points to, although it may invalidate it.

Comment: To give a wider picture: The underlying reason this is done that way is const-correctness: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#overview-const

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not the iterator is const doesn't matter, since the container is the thing being modified (and `insert` is not a `const`-qualified member function), not the passed in iterator.

And this just makes it easier to use. A non-const `iterator` is convertible to a `const_iterator` (but not the other way around) so you can still easily use an `iterator`.

A somewhat relevant paper: https://wg21.link/N2350

Comment: In particular, I could have `std::vector<int>::const_iterator findSpecialItem(const std::vector<int>& v);` and could want to then do `auto it = findSpecialItem(v); v.insert(it, 42);`. If `insert` required an `iterator`, then we’d have to jump through hoops to turn `it` from a `const_iterator` to an `iterator`.